Dynamically create or delete kubernetes manifest
I want to leverage Amazon EKS to host a platform where users can deploy their containerized applications. Additionally, I plan to utilize an ALB for host-based routing, directing incoming requests to specific applications running on the platform. I cannot obtain container information (e.g., Docker image, hostname, etc.) until requests are accepted, so I cannot define Kubernetes manifest beforehand. In my view, I need to dynamically create or delete manifests corresponding to users' requests, and then trigger Kubernetes deployments to update ALB, Route53, and EKS accordingly.
However, since the Kubernetes manifests are version-controlled on GitLab, modifying them dynamically may not adhere to best practices.
Are there any recommended best practices for implementing this platform?


Why not use ALB to route all traffic to an Ingress proxy(Say Istio Ingress Gateway) and let ingress proxy do the routing based on L7 parameters like URI, Methods, Headers etc. If your requirement is to have a unique hostname for all Applications, even then I would use the Ingress proxy to do that, and just automate the registration of host Alias in Route53 (It can be done via Application deployment pipeline)

The ingress proxy is still managed by a Kubernetes manifest, right? From my perspective, it seems that this approach will encounter the same issue of dynamically updating the manifest according to users' requests.
